# money_format returning two different things on different servers

Tags: php, linux

I have an issue with php locality settings.  I have a dev and a production server.

when I execute the following statement

```
echo money_format('%i', '89.95');
```

on one server I get 89.95 back, on the other I get USD 89.95.  This is causing some formatting errors on the server returning USD 89.95.

It appears to just have started happening today, so I am wondering if this is a server settings issue somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe they have different locale setting? Try adding `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');` before the echo

Comment: Have a look at the comments section at http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: thanks for the help, it is most likely a server issue I think. We have multiple prod servers all running the same code and have isolated it to just one of the production servers that is producing different outputs then the rest.

Comment: We rebooted the server and the problem fixed itself. Thanks